# Integral with imaginary exponentials.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

TL DR - Why is $\int_{x=0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i x} dx}{e^{ix}-0.4} = 2\pi$ but $\int_{x=0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i x} dx}{e^{ix}-2.5} = 0$

When doing some Fourier analysis related stuff, I came across some weird integrals.

My goal was to integrate (where k is a parameter) $\int_{x=0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i x} e^{i k x} dx}{(e^{ix}-0.4)(e^{ix}-2.5)}$. Proceeding using partial fractions, we need the integrals $\int_{x=0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i x} e^{i k x}dx}{e^{ix}-0.4}$ and $\int_{x=0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i x} e^{i k x}dx}{e^{ix}-2.5}$.

My first attempt was to write them as power series -  $\frac{e^{i x}}{e^{ix}-0.4} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (0.4e^{-ix})^n$ and $\int_{x=0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i x} e^{i k x}dx}{e^{ix}-0.4} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (0.4)^n\delta(k-n) = (0.4)^k$.

I thought I can do something similar for the 2.5 case and I get $\int_{x=0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i x} e^{i k x} dx}{(e^{ix}-0.4)(e^{ix}-2.5)} = \frac{1}{2.1} \left((2.5)^k - (0.4)^k \right)$ which is $0$ for $k=0$, and I know this is not true.

Trying these integrals on wolfram alpha gives $\int_{x=0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i x} dx}{e^{ix}-0.4} = 2\pi$  [Alpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20e%5E(i%20x)%2F((e%5E(ix)-0.4))%20for%20x%3D0%20to%202pi) but $\int_{x=0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i x} dx}{e^{ix}-2.5} = 0$ [Alpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20e%5E(i%20x)%2F(e%5E(ix)-2.5)%20for%20x%3D0%20to%202pi). Why is this so?

I know some basics about convergence but not how it applies inside integrals. Maybe I can't expand the power series for 2.5 because it won't converge? Otherwise, how can I show this integral to be 0?

Comment: Rewrite:$$\int_0^{2\pi}f(e^{ix})e^{ix}~\mathrm dx=\frac1i\int_{|z|=1}f(z)~\mathrm dz$$By theorems of complex analysis, this depends on whether or not $f$ has a pole on $|z|\le1$. For the first, this pole occurs at $0.4<1$, for the second, it occurs at $2.5>1$.

Comment: I have minimal knowledge of complex integration and understand your approach, but can there be a more "first principles" approach? Also, where does my approach fail?